# Рисование в PyQt без предварительной очистки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qpainter, paintevent

Проблема в том, что, когда рисуется новый прямоугольник, а старый исчезает, 
т.е. насколько я понимаю перед рисованием поле окна очищается и все окно рисуется заново.

Как сделать, чтобы поле не очищалось, а только прорисовывались те участки, 
в которых должна рисоваться новая фигура, если это возможно?

**main.py**:

```
class ExampleDraw(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.point = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.point['x'] = QMouseEvent.pos().x()
        self.point['y'] = QMouseEvent.pos().y()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        paint = QPainter(self)
        paint.setBrush(QColor(50, 200, 50, 255))
        paint.drawRect(self.point['x'], self.point['y'], 50, 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Instruction:
    def paint(self, painter):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class LineInstruction(Instruction):
    def __init__(self, e): 
        self._e = e

    def paint(self, painter):
        painter.setBrush(QColor(50, 200, 50, 255))
        painter.drawRect(self._e) 

class ContextTest:
    instructions = []        


class ExampleDraw(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event): 
        e = QRect(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y(), 50, 50)
        instruction = LineInstruction(e) 
        ContextTest.instructions.append(instruction)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super().paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        qp = QPainter(self)
        for instruction in ContextTest.instructions:
            instruction.paint(qp)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ExampleDraw()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант ВТОРОЙ:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(600, 400)
        self.pixmap.fill(QColor(239, 239, 239, 180)) 

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.mousePressEvent = self.get_pos

    def drawPoints(self, pos):
        pen = QPen(QColor(50, 200, 50, 170), 50)
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self.label.pixmap())
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawPoint(pos.x(), pos.y())
        self.label.update()

    def get_pos(self, event):
        X = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()
        self.drawPoints(event.pos())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainGui()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, этот вариант не подойдет. В моем приложении подобное сделано и когда при обходе цикла нужно рисовать 2000+ прямоугольников заметно падение производительности. Вот потому хотелось бы подобное как в Javascript canvas.clearRect очищать участок, если это надо, а лучше не очищать, те места которые вообщем-то не нужно обновлять. Мне из-за того, что обновить цвет одного небольшого участка приходится перерисовывать все(а это проход по массиву длиной в 2000+ объектов).

Comment: Я добавил еще один пример, пробуйте.